# Is there a way to print ranges using for in a single line in python

Tags: python, for-loop, primes, division

So, here is my code for calculating if a number is prime or not. It also if a number is prime or not prints out the divisors of the number. My problem comes when i try to print divisors of non prime numbers in a list in a single line.

```
x=int(input())
if x<0:
    print("you did not enter a natural nubmer")
else:
    if x > 1:
        for i in range(2, x//2):
            if (x % i) == 0:
                print(x, "is not a prime number")
                for n in range (2, x-1):
                    if x%n==0:
                        print[n]
                break
        else:
            print(x, "is a prime nubmer")
            print([1,x])
    else:
        print(x, "is not a prime number")
        for n in range (2, x-1):
                    if x%n==0:
                        print[n]
```

For example 8, it will print that it is not a prime number, then it will print [2] and  [4], but i want it to print [2,4]. Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) is about :

```
divs = [n for n in range(2, x - 1) if x % n == 0]
print(divs) # [2, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

to print multiple times without going on next line you can use this part of code:
print(n,end=" "). So you code becomes like this:

```
x=int(input())
if x<0:
    print("you did not enter a natural nubmer")
else:
    if x > 1:
        for i in range(2, x//2):
            if (x % i) == 0:
                print(x, "is not a prime number")
                for n in range (2, x-1):
                    if x%n==0:
                        print(n,end=" ")
                break
        else:
            print(x, "is a prime nubmer")
            print([1,x])
    else:
        print(x, "is not a prime number")
        for n in range (2, x-1):
                    if x%n==0:
                        print[n]
```

Comment: Than you for your answers.